# How to SSH from local linux into specific directory on windows 10 remote

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, windows-10, git-bash

I want to ssh from my local linux computer into a specific directory on a windows 10 remote. The shell that is used on the remote is git bash. I don't want to keep changing the directory every time I log into my remote using ssh.

for linux remotes this is easily done using something like this:

```
ssh -t user@x.x.x.x "cd /targetDir ; \$SHELL --login"
```

**The question is how can the same thing be achieved for Windows 10 remotes?** If nothing else works I would also accept changing the default entry point in git bash for any ssh sessions on the remote.

Please note that I am not looking for help setting up ssh (already works). I just want to jump right into a specific directory when a session is started.

Comment: `git bash` is a shell, it's not an OpenSSH server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse. If you prefer to use something more intended for Windows, there WinRM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/portal

Comment: not sure what you mean. if the shell on the remote is already git bash, you should be able to do the same 'cd ; shell' pattern or arguments?

Comment: OpenSSH Server is already installed and working on Win10. 
I have changed the default shell to git bash. All that is left to do is jumping right into the desired directory when a session is started. The example I have shown does not work. Session is initialised but then  the terminal remains at the local machine after password prompt goes through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this thing out myself. The following command gets the job done. Using double and single quotes together is required to make it work (in no particular order).

```
ssh -t user@x.x.x.x "'cd /targetDir ; bash'"
```